# How to quit bash if one of the script it executes fail?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that executes a bunch of ruby scripts.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ruby script_1.rb

ruby script_2.rb

ruby script_3.rb
```

If any of the ruby scripts fail it exists using `exit` with code `1`. In the case of an exit how can I also exit the bash script midway?

I understand that bash can exit using `exit N` but how can it catch exit from ruby? Should the ruby script throw an execption for this to work?

Comment: What's the return code of your ruby script if it fails and what if it ends correct?

Comment: If the ruby script exits with `exit (false)`, your problem is trivial.  If the ruby script exits `exit(true)`, your problem is more challenging.

Comment: @Cyrus I am doing `exit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do anything fancy.  (`set -e` is fancy, or perhaps pathological.  Many will suggest using it.  Ignore them)

Just do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby script_1.rb &&
ruby script_2.rb &&
ruby script_3.rb
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby script_1.rb || exit 1
ruby script_2.rb || exit 1
ruby script_3.rb || exit 1
```

You may be tempted to add additional error messages.  Avoid that temptation.  If you need an error message, it should be written by the ruby script, since it has details about what the error is.

Comment: Why is `-e` _fancy, or perhaps pathological_?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 1):

You can check the exit code with `$?`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ruby script_1.rb

if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
 exit 1
fi

#...
```

You can use a helper function to do the same check over and over again:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function exit_if_code {
    if [[ $? == $1 ]]; then
        exit $1
    fi    
}

ruby script_1.rb

exit_if_code 1

ruby script_2.rb

exit_if_code 1

ruby script_3.rb

exit_if_code 1
```

Comment: I suggest to use `exit 1`.

Comment: @Cyrus yep, I that's for the OP to decide but I'll edit the function to exit with the code that triggers the exit